# MVC HTML Set img class name from a variable in view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to set class name to img tags and the name should be string + variable from my view, (Edit + variable).

```
@{int rows = 1;}

@foreach (var file in Model)
{  
    <img class='"Edit"+@rows' src="~/Content/images/edit.png" />
    FileIconRow++;
}
```

So the class names should be Edit1, Edit2, Edit3 etc for every model it loops through.

Is this even possible? I'm not getting it to work, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img class='Edit_@rows' src="~/Content/images/edit.png" />
...
rows++;
```

OR

```
<img class='Edit@(rows)' src="~/Content/images/edit.png" />
..
rows++;
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, the first one didn't work but the second one did. Faaanx!

Comment: first one output: `Edit_1, Edit_2, ...`

Comment: @downvoter, you should explain why did you downvote?

Answer (score -1):

```
@{int rows = 1;}
@foreach (var file in Model)
{  
    <img class='"Edit"+@rows' src="~/Content/images/edit.png" />

    rows++;
}
```

Why are you incrementing `FileIconRow++`? You have taken `@row` variable as counter you should be increment `@row` and this is to be used in class name as shown above.

Comment: Its not copy of code . @jww was incrementing FileIconRow++;         But he should be increment the row variable that he have taken as a counter. I think you should got my point.

Comment: @jww thanks you saw difference :) please upvote my answer as by mistake people are downvote me but my answer is correct.  And thnks for suggestion I have edited my answer with explanation